# Creating a vector with numbers "partnered" with other numbers in another vector

Tags: r, vector

I have 5 vectors, 2 of which I consider "paired," meaning they have the same number of elements and the corresponding elements in each vector go with each other (in my case, alphas and betas I have specified for different Beta distributions).  I would like to make a matrix of all the combinations of the elements of the three unpaired vectors and the pairs of elements in the other 2 vectors.  The way I have thought to do this was to make combinations of the elements of one vector from the pair with the other three non-paired vectors, then match up elements of the left-out paired vector with their partners.  I've made the combinations, but am struggling to do the 2nd part - pairing up the elements after the combinations are made.  Here's my code for the first part:

```
l <- list(alpha=c(8.572, 20, 23.333, 45), n=c(10, 20, 40), numc=c(2, 3, 5), numq=c(5, 10, 20))  
combo <- expand.grid(l)
beta <- c(20, 20, 10, 5)
```

The first few lines of the "combo" object look like this:

```
    alpha  n numc numq
1  8.572 10    2    5
2 20.000 10    2    5
3 23.333 10    2    5
4 45.000 10    2    5
5  8.572 20    2    5
6 20.000 20    2    5
```

Now I'd like to insert a vector into this data frame called "beta" which pairs each alpha value (indexed 1 through 4) with the corresponding beta value from the beta vector I specified. So for example, whenever alpha is 8.572, beta is 20.  How can I do this?

Comment: Isn't this just `combo$beta <- beta`? Though if the data wasn't already sorted (like in your case) you could also do `combo$beta <- beta[match(combo$alpha, l$alpha)]` probably

Comment: Oh, yes it is.  Thanks.  It looks like this only works because the alpha values are cycling through one at a time, but if I had alpha second or third or fourth in the list then ran it through expand.grid, this wouldn't work.  But that's fine.

Comment: Then `match` will work. Or `factor` like in the answer below

Answer (score -1):

I think what you want is

```
alpha <- factor(combo$alpha)
beta <- factor(beta)
combo$beta <- beta[alpha]
```

Not sure why you would need match if you can just use the levels of the factor? For example, suppose you randomly permuted alpha.

```
sa <- sample(alpha)
combo$beta <- beta[sa]
```

This should still be correct.

Following you comment, @David Arenburg:

```
l <- list(alpha=c(23.333, 20, 45, 8.572), 
     n=c(10, 20, 40), numc=c(2, 3, 5), numq=c(5, 10, 20)) 
combo <- expand.grid(l)
beta <- factor(c(20, 20, 10, 5))
alpha <- factor(combo$alpha)
combo$beta <- beta[alpha]
```

Isn't this still exactly what OP wants?

```
 head(combo)
   alpha  n numc numq beta
1 23.333 10    2    5   10
2 20.000 10    2    5   20
3 45.000 10    2    5    5
4  8.572 10    2    5   20
5 23.333 20    2    5   10
6 20.000 20    2    5   20
```

You might consider if you want to map the nth element in one numeric vector to some factor, that you treat the numeric vector as an ordered factor. That way, you can specify the ordering, and it won't be contingent on your initial ordering of beta.

Here, I switched the order of beta and I provided levels to the ordered factor alpha, which were specified according to your original order.

```
l <- list(alpha=c(23.333, 20, 45, 8.572), 
     n=c(10, 20, 40), numc=c(2, 3, 5), numq=c(5, 10, 20)) 
combo <- expand.grid(l)
beta <- factor(c(20, 10, 20, 5))
alpha <- as.ordered(factor(combo$alpha, 
                           levels = c(8.572, 20, 23.333, 45)))
combo$beta <- beta[alpha]
```

You will note that the nth element of the levels of alpha were mapped to the nth element of beta, as you originally wanted.

If not, I advise you to use `match`.

Comment: Because relying on `factor` setting the levels by itself is dangerous. If `alpha` is not in acceding order, then your solution won't work. Consider the following example `alpha <- factor(c(2, 1, 4, 3)) ; beta <- c(20, 10, 10, 5) ; beta[alpha]`

Comment: Oh, perhaps it is because you aren't factoring both of them?

Comment: In your example, `alpha` starts with `23.333` and `beta` with `20`, while the first line of `head(combo)` shows `beta == 10` when `alpha == 23.333`, so no it doesn't seem to work correctly

Comment: But OP wants alpha value of 23.333 to map to beta values of 10?

Comment: Yes, I want alpha values of 23.333 to map to beta values of 10 because in my original example these are each the third elements of their respective vectors.

Comment: `match` isn't converting anything to `character` vectors. Have no idea what you trying to say there

Comment: Internally, `match` is a shortcut for `x %in% table`, which first converts them into a character. The table created by `match(x, table)` contains dimnames of the levels of this factor stored as a character.  Then it coerces x and table to a common type based on R's internal ordering of types before matching.

Comment: `%in%` is running `match`, not the other way around. And no one converted to a factor except you. I suggested to use `match` on a numeric vector that OP originally had. When doing `str(match(1:4, 2:3))` I don't see any levels or characters

Comment: It does so internally. It is in the help page `?match`. You're right, `%in%` is the alias for match not the other way around. I removed the reference so as not to confuse OP. Anyways, the only reason I pursued this method instead of match, which is much faster (it's written in C after all) and easier to use is because of the way the question was asked. The OP preferred to associate the levels of one numeric vector with that of another. This jumped off the page telling me to treat this vector as a factor. Lila Tov David it's late here.